# Obtain the percentage of groupby() count(), save it and plot it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following,

```
    Time                    Value   Cluster
1   2020-08-11 06:09:59     0       0
2   2020-08-11 06:14:59     0       12
3   2020-08-11 06:19:59     1       103
4   2020-08-11 06:24:59     0       0
5   2020-08-11 06:29:59     0       12
```

Basically there are 3 columns, the first one is date and time (`Time`), the second one refers to the group to which the data belongs (`Cluster`) and the third one (`Value`) is the result (in binary).

Therefore, what I would like is to be able to make a statistic according to the group that I am in this instant, the probability that the next instant the result is 1 or 0.

I have thought of the following,

1. Move the result column (`Value`) one position (one instant of time).
2. Group the data and count them.

This is the code I have made, for a single cluster,

```
test_df[(test_df['Cluster'] == 2)].groupby('ValueT1')['Cluster'].count()
```

With this out:

```
ValueT1
0    7406
1    7787
Name: Cluster, dtype: int64
```

My question is, how do you get the percentage from here? Could you make a double bar chart (one next to the other with the set of clusters)?

For the above example I would like to have as a result something similar to the following,

```
ValueT1
0 48.7%
1 51.2%
Name: Cluster, dtype: int64
```

And in addition, I would like to have a graph that gathers these percentages for each of the clusters.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `df.value_counts(['Cluster', 'Value'], normalize=True)`? In fact, what is the expected result for your sample?

Comment: @Corralien I modified my question. I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. Thank you

Comment: Try: `df.groupby('Cluster')['Value'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to know the percentage of 0 and 1 by cluster. You can use `groupby / value_counts` to do that.

Setup a MRE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(2023)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': rng.choice([0, 1], 1000),
                   'Cluster': rng.choice(range(12), 1000)})
```

Output:

```
stats = df.groupby('Cluster')['Value'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
print(stats)

# Output
Cluster  Value
0        1        51.219512
         0        48.780488
1        0        54.545455
         1        45.454545
2        0        54.320988
         1        45.679012
3        1        53.658537
         0        46.341463
4        0        57.647059
         1        42.352941
5        0        51.428571
         1        48.571429
6        0        51.086957
         1        48.913043
7        1        55.128205
         0        44.871795
8        0        50.632911
         1        49.367089
9        1        51.485149
         0        48.514851
10       0        51.250000
         1        48.750000
11       0        58.536585
         1        41.463415
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

**Update**:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

stats = stats.rename('PCT').reset_index()

f1 = stats[stats['Value'] == 0]
f2 = stats[stats['Value'] == 1]
clusters = stats['Cluster'].unique()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=clusters, y=f1['PCT'], name='0'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=clusters, y=f2['PCT'], name='1'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! It is possible to plot this using bargroup form plotly? :)

Comment: I don't know about plotly but I think it's possible

Comment: Is it what you expect?